# My cnn model is getting high validation accuracy but when i test it only show 3 classes its suppouse to show 26 classes

Tags: conv-neural-network

I have created a CNN model to detect asl signs its getting high accuracy values in a small number of epochs but when I test it with the camera it always shows the same 3 classes its supposed to show 26 classes and it only shows the last three classes

Comment: Please, when you ask a question always bring a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.